# im getting somekind of logical error in this function instead of data saved on .txt file by write function it gives strange numbers

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
class Admin
{
public:
string name,fathername;
void ViewStudent(Admin obj);
}
```

This is function Body

```
void Admin::ViewStudent(Admin obj)
{
CLS();
ifstream file;
file.open(STDF, ios::in|ios::binary);
while (!file.eof()){
    file.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
    if (file.eof())
    {
        break;
    }
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << fathername << endl;
}
PUS();}
```

This is Main where function is called

```
case 5:
{
Admin usr;
CLS();
usr.ViewStudent(usr);
}
break;
```

So when i run this program first it saves data in Admin class object then saved in text file by write function and when i try to read data from that file with this function it gives me exception error

Comment: `file.read((char*)this, sizeof(this));` -- What is `Admin`?  If it is not a trivially-copyable type, or it contains pointer members, this will not work.  You cannot read bytes into an object and think you are creating an object.  You need to properly serialize the data.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Please post a [mcve] / [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Make sure none of the member variables of Admin are `std::string`

Comment: OT: `file.close();` is not needed. The file will close when file goes out of scope.

Comment: `#include <algorithm>...std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<Admin>();` -- @OP -- include that header, and put that `cout` line in `main`.  If the result is `0`, then your method of reading and writing will not work.  If your `Admin` contains pointers, your method of reading and writing will not work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes the output is 0 but Admin class does not contain any pointers but is has string data members.

Comment: Then you can't read into it as you're doing it now.   You should overload `operator >>` for `Admin` (and also `<<`) and read/write to a file that way.  I see so many questions here that make the same mistake you're making with the "binary file reading/writing", so it seems that this method is being taught out there by some book or website, when it is actually wrong to use it here.

Comment: You cannot just dump the binary representation of a non-POD object to disk and read it back. You need to transform it (serialize it) into a form that can be persisted and read back (deserialized). Anything that contains pointers (like `std::string`) can't just be naively saved like this, the pointers will not be valid when you read them back.

Comment: @JesperJuhl will this work if i use char array instead of strings?

Comment: @Yurnero Yes. If you do it correctly. But then you are just exchanging one set of problems for another - now you have none of the flexibility and  conveniences of std::string but all the problems of a fixed size array. And you will still have the same problem with *any other class* that is not a POD. It might solve your immediate problem, but it's like pissing your pants to stay warm in a blizzard; it'll work for 30 seconds but leave you no better (or worse) off after that. Just learn about serialization/de-serialization already. And you can get a char array from a string btw.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ifstream file; file.open(STDF, ios::in|ios::binary);` to `ifstream file(STDF, ios::in|ios::binary);`.